# How to access standard *this behaviour after overloading operator*?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a wrapper for an iterator, and trying to make it behave just like the contained iterator.

For this, it requires to overload both operator* and operator++, but this poses the following problem:

```
//Typedefs to make below code easier to read
typedef std::map::const_iterator<std::string, SomeClass> iteratorAlias;
typedef std::pair<const std::string, SomeClass> mapPairAlias;

class IteratorWrapper
{
    iteratorAlias iterator;

    /*Other code omitted*/

    mapPairAlias& operator*()
    {
        return *iterator;
    }

    const mapPairAlias& operator*() const
    {
        return *iterator;
    }

    IteratorWrapper& operator++()
    {
        ++this->iterator;
        return *this;
    }

    IteratorWrapper operator++(int)
    {
        IteratorWrapper copy(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return copy;
    }
};
```

In both operator++ functions, `this` needs to be dereferenced. But it looks like that would result in getting the `mapPairAlias` from the overloaded function, in stead of the `IteratorWrapper`.

How should this issue be resolved? The STL iterators handle both functions just fine, so presumably there is a way.

Comment: No, `this` is a raw pointer so `*this` simply dereferences it.

Comment: @Brian Oooooh, I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a raw pointer to the current instance

`*this` is a reference to the current instance

`**this` is syntactic sugar for `this->operator*()`

So the issue you described does not exist, `*this` will do what you want just fine.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll accept this as soon as this awkward 10 minute wait is over.